# Authorising with Node, serving with Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

I expect this question has been answered, but because I'm unsure of the terminology I might have missed, or not understood the answer.

I would like to use Nodejs to authorise and parse a GET request, i.e:

```
something.com/app/?key=12345&files=all
```

Then once this is read by node, key authorised, and the files requested compiled, node would tell Nginx to serve back some static files based on this request.

- So, is this possible?
- Is there a better way of doing this (I have seen a lot about serving
  static files with Nginx instead of Nodejs)

*edit* - Just to inform, i'm using Express, routing is not my problem. Its just I don't know how to pass a successful request back to Nginx, or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do token authentication. 
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSecureLinkModule

Your nodejs app could generate signed links, and nginx handles all aspects of serving the file.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options with NodeJs:

- [ExpressJs](http://expressjs.com/).
- [Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/)